# How to optimize logo section on WordPress Divi Website?

Tags: wordpress, optimization, wordpress-gutenberg, divi

[image]I need to align these logos horizontally on one line like it is for Desktop View. Should I use the Row setting or change logos separately?
What do I do to make these logos look like in the image attached on a mobile device using DIVI Page builder in WordPress?

[image: Logo Grid Optimization]